# Problemas com resultado do RowFilter

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

Estou trabalhando com *DocumentListener* e *RowFilter*, e percebi que o meu filtro esta pegando o dado que eu digito, e buscando por correspondência em todas as colunas da minha tabela. Eu gostaria de saber, como que poderia escolher a coluna que ele deve comparar, e também, como eu deveria fazer para que ele pegue só as palavras que o começo seja igual o que foi digitado.

**Exemplo consulta:**

Ucrânia → começa com U

Brasil

Portugal → Tem a letra U, porém, não começa com a letra U, deve ignora - la

USA → começa com U

Digito U, ele só me mostraria USA e Ucrânia.

**Exemplo código:**

```
package teste;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestX extends JFrame {

    private String[] colunas
            = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

    private Object[][] dados = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dados, colunas);
    private JTable tabela = new JTable(model);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tabela.getModel());

    private JTextField barraPesquisa = new JTextField();
    private JButton botao = new JButton("OK");

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public TestX() {
        add(x());
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent x() {
        JPanel painelX = new JPanel();
        painelX.setLayout(null);

        painelX.add(barraPesquisa);
        barraPesquisa.setBounds(20, 10, 270, 27);
        painelX.add(botao);
        botao.setBounds(300, 10, 65, 27);

        barraPesquisa.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();

                //model.setRowCount(0); // limpar as linhas
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    barraPesquisa.setText("Digite aqui..");
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                    model.getRowCount();
                }
                label.setText(rowSorter.getViewRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
                label.setText(rowSorter.getViewRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            }
        });

        tabela.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        painelX.add(tabela);
        tabela.setBounds(5, 100, 500, 150);

        painelX.add(label);
        label.setBounds(10, 250, 150, 30);
        label.setText(model.getRowCount() + " resultados encontrados!");

        painelX.setBounds(1, 1, 600, 400);
        return painelX;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestX t = new TestX();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua pesquisa nao retorna nada apenas com a letra `U`

Comment: @diegofm não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Nesse código, pesquisar por U nao filtra nada.

Comment: É apenas um exemplo, se vc pesquisar com outra letra, G por exemplo, ele vai trazer outros resultados.

Comment: Gustavo da uma olhada no link, vc apagou a pergunta mas eu estava testando seu código e acabei achando um jeito independente daqueles links que sugeri: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63959/criando-checkboxlist-em-swing

Comment: @Articuno eu tinha apagado porque como ja tinha la a resposta achei que n ia precisar da pergunta mais, se quiser eu faço novamente pra vc colocar a sua resposta

Comment: Teste o código lá do chat do link, mas acho que as respostas que indiquei são mais completas. Só quis deixar mais uma opção além dos links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for só para limitar que o filtro pesquise a partir da inicial das palavras da tabela, basta mudar seu filtro para:

```
rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("^(?i)" + text));
```

O `^` irá fazer com que o filtro seja aplicado a partir do começo da linha, e não em qualquer posição que for encontrado o termo pesquisado.

Outros `Patterns` podem ser consultados [nesta página](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

Você também pode criar filtros diferentes para cada coluna ou limitar a apenas algumas, usando alguns métodos da classe `RowFilter`.Partindo do código apresentado na pergunta, para restringir a pesquisa apenas a primeira coluna, basta informar o índice da coluna no próprio [`RowFilter.regexFilter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter(java.lang.String,%20int...)):

```
// o indice 0 filtrará apenas a primeira coluna
rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("^(?i)" + text, 0));
```

Comment: Ele continua a pegar fora a primeira letra. Se você pesquisar "N", ele traz Norway e India, a letra n é apenas a segunda na palavra India.

Comment: @GustavoSantos ele traz a linha da india por causa da cidade de "New delhi".

Comment: Então, no RowFilter existe algum tipo de "getColumn" ? algo que de pra escolher a coluna que deve ser procurado a ocorrência do dado/letra que foi digitado ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos você quer restringir em qual coluna deve ser feita a pesquisa? Se sim, é perfeitamente possivel, basta dizer qual a coluna que quer restringir para pesquisa que eu edito a resposta.

Comment: a segunda coluna, assim a primeira eu sempre deixo código/ID.

Comment: @GustavoSantos a coluna de cidades?

Comment: desculpa, esqueci que a ordem no exemplo ta diferente, pode fazer com a primeira coluna. Obrigado !

Comment: @GustavoSantos editado

Comment: Deu certinho, não achei que seria tão simples a solução, obrigado !